# Magento can't see files located in local/NameSpace/ModuleName/

Tags: module, magento1.9.0.1

I've created simple module with couple controllers.
Tested on local machine - everything works fine. But when i am trying move my module to live server - my module doen't works.(I get 404 everytime i am trying to get frontednMapping/controller/action).
Module structure is

/app/code/local/Amo/module/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amo_module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Amo_module>
    </modules>
    <!-- This node contains parameters, available on frontend -->
    <frontend>
        <!-- Module aliases are located in this block -->
        <routers>
            <!-- This node's name should be the same as our alias -->
            <module>
                <!-- use parameter specifies which of basic routers needs to be used.
                This can be "standard" for frontend or "admin" for backend -->
                <use>standard</use>
                <!-- router arguments block -->
                <args>
                    <!-- This parameter specifies the full name of out module -->
                    <module>Amo_module</module>
                    <!-- This parameter sets module alias -->
                    <frontName>adtfnc</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                    <file>amomodule.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Amo/module/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Amo_module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "test data is OK";
    }

   }
```

/app/etc/modules/Amo_module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amo_module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Amo_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

On dev machine i get such info for my module:

```
var_dump(Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Amo_module'));
echo Mage::getUrl('module/index/index');

object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)[551]
  public 'active' => string 'true' (length=4)
  public 'codePool' => string 'local' (length=5)
  public 'version' => string '0.1.0' (length=5)
http://magento.local/adtfnc/index/index/
```

same info on live

```
object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)#853 (2) { 
["active"]=> string(4) "true" 
["codePool"]=> string(5) "local" } 
http://live.server/module/index/index/
```

As we can there is no module version and magento(as i understand) can see frontend mapping for my module. Error.log is empty. Apache config same for dev and live machine.

Comment: Feel free to accept any one of the answer. Please dont leave your question as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The module name should start with a capital letter. So instead of `Amo_module` name it `Amo_Module`.

Comment: hmm.. I was sure you will answer this question first. Because @marius is awake and active :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt. Damn...silly news travels fast. :)

Comment: I was the one who talked you in twitter before you "AWAKE" :) -rajKtomy

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Everything works fine. Sorry for silly questions.

Comment: Happy to hear. Every one does make mistakes. Accept One of our answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your module name's first letter should be Capital letter.

That is your location should be in `app/code/local/Amo/Module`

Your etc/modules xml file should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amo_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Amo_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Your controller should look like `Amo_Module_IndexContorller`.

You need to change your module definition as `Amo_Module` in everywhere